# Bar chart plugin - IE9-110 issue with chart expanding outside of container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, bar-chart

I've made a simple bar chart plugin which takes some settings and data and displays it as a percentage, it's working perfectly fine in all browsers except IE9-10.

The chart still displays fine yet there is a weird 'jump' once each of the bars have finished animating where the table seems to gain additional height. I've measured the height of the bars in the chart in browsers where it's working fine and there appears to be an additional ~50px height being added in browsers where the weird 'jump' effect occurs.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
#barchart {
  text-align: center;
}

.bar {
  margin-right: 10px;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-top: 50px;
  height: 100%;
}

.bar .label {
  text-align: center;
  width: inherit;
  margin: 0 auto 20px auto;
  width: 116px;
}

.bar__value {
  height: 0%;
  background-repeat: repeat-y;
  background-position: top center;
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

And here is the JS:

```
var Crafted = (function(c) {
  return c;
})(Crafted || {});

(function($, c) {

  c.BarChart = (function() {

    var barChart = function(target, options, data) {
      this.target = target;
      this.ChartItem(options);
      this.data = data;
      this.create();
    };

    barChart.prototype.ChartItem = function(options) {
      var settings = $.extend({
        width: '100%',
        height: '500px',
        usePercentSymbol: false,
        delay: 1000,
        animSpeed: 1000,
        chartImage: '',
        chartBgColour: '#CCCCCC'
      }, options);

      this.width = settings.width;
      this.height = settings.height;
      this.usePercentSymbol = settings.usePercentSymbol;
      this.delay = settings.delay;
      this.animSpeed = settings.animSpeed;
      this.chartImage = settings.chartImage;
      this.chartBgColour = settings.chartBgColour;
      return this;
    };

    barChart.prototype.create = function() {

      var _self = this;

      if (!_self.target) {
        console.error('Error: BarChart \'target\' must be specified');
        return;
      }

      if (!_self.data) {
        console.error('Error: BarChart \'data\' must be provided');
        return;
      }

      var $barChart = $('<table></table>').attr('id', 'barchart');
      var $charts = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('data-row');

      $charts.appendTo($barChart);
      $barChart.appendTo(_self.target);
      $barChart.attr('width', _self.width)
        .attr('height', _self.height);

      $.each(_self.data, function(index, value) {
        var $chart = $('<td></td>')
          .addClass('bar')
          .attr('valign', 'bottom')
          .attr('data-percent', value.percent);
        $chart.appendTo($charts);

        var $chartLabel = $('<div></div>').addClass('label');
        $chartLabel.appendTo($chart);

        var $chartValue = $('<div></div>').addClass('label__percent').text(_self.usePercentSymbol ? '0%' : 0);
        $chartValue.appendTo($chartLabel);

        var $chartTitle = $('<div></div>').addClass('label__title').text(value.label);
        $chartTitle.appendTo($chartLabel);

        var $barValue = $('<div></div>').addClass('bar__value');

        var barStyle = _self.chartImage ?
          'background-image:url(\'' + _self.chartImage + '\');' :
          'background-color:' + _self.chartBgColour

        $barValue.attr('style', barStyle);
        $barValue.appendTo($chart);
      });

      setTimeout(function() {
        $('.bar').each(function() {
          var percentage = $(this).attr('data-percent');
          var $percentLbl = $(this).find('.label__percent');

          $(this).children('.bar__value').animate({
            height: percentage + '%'
          }, _self.animSpeed);

          $({
            countNum: 0
          }).animate({
            countNum: percentage
          }, {
            duration: _self.animSpeed,
            easing: 'linear',
            progress: function() {
              var currentValue = Math.floor(this.countNum);
              $percentLbl.text(_self.usePercentSymbol ? currentValue + '%' : currentValue);
            }
          });
        });
      }, _self.delay);
    };

    return barChart;
  })();

})(jQuery, Crafted);

$(function() {
  (function(c) {
    var settings = {
      width: '800px',
      height: '400px',
      usePercentSymbol: true,
      delay: 200,
      animSpeed: 1000,
      chartImage: 'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/662693/chimney.svg'
    };

    var data = [{
      label: 'MANCHESTER',
      percent: 78
    }, {
      label: 'BIRMINGHAM',
      percent: 69
    }, {
      label: 'LONDON',
      percent: 94
    }, {
      label: 'CARDIFF',
      percent: 39
    }, {
      label: 'GLASGOW',
      percent: 54
    }, {
      label: 'BELFAST',
      percent: 35
    }]

    var barChart = new c.BarChart('#barChart', settings, data);

  })(Crafted);
});
```

I have a [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/60abgbqk/1/) that demonstrates the problem. If you load this in IE9/10 (you can use the browser emulator in IE dev tools - F12) you will see the strange effect I'm talking about. This doesn't occur in IE11/Edge etc...

Could it be due to the padding top applied to the `<td>` elements? This is used to give enough spacing for each chart label to prevent them from being cut off.

Answer (score 0):

try with this css modification to bar class

```
.bar {
 margin-right: 10px;
 position: relative;  
 bottom: 0;
 overflow: hidden;
 padding-top: 50px;
 height: 75%;
```

}

seems it works either on ie9/10 and chrome

Comment: Whilst this does get rid of the weird jumping effect it does mean that the bars are 50px smaller than they should be on IE9/10

Comment: I hope this comment can be usefull than my last one :) if you change this line var $charts = $('<tr></tr>').addClass('data-row'); with this var $charts = $('<tr style="height:485px;"></tr>').addClass('data-row'); the jump effect is not shown.

Comment: This works in the fiddle however if you add the code to a full page you get the same issue, I think it my just be a side effect of being in JsFiddle. How did you come up with the 485px value? Is it a based on the table height or something?

Comment: I thought that the problem was the tr height, so I've used a value a bit more of chart's dimension to contain it.

Comment: I'll try doing table height + 50px (to account for td padding) and see if that helps

Comment: Yeah it works if I increase the tr height to around 800px but again, the overall table height is still 50px bigger than it should be, is there some special way that IE9/10 handle padding on <td> elements?